# Workflow stuck on WaitForFieldChange

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow-activity

I have a problem with VS workflow which gets stuck on the WaitForFieldChange activity. Nothing is displayed, the activity simply does not detect a change in the field (change verified with SharePoint Manager directly on the task list). Can the problem be happening because the field has a space in name? I have used WaitForFieldChange in other cases and there was no problem there. Does the activity have any special requirements as to how the list and field should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to recreate from scratch the lists which workflow used and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with WaitForFieldChange in the past. The workaround I use in these cases is to use a WaitForItemEvent activity and set the EventName to "When an item is updated". The rest you can see in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: this looks great, will try and see how it goes

Comment: unfortunately this also doesn't work. workflow does not detect update. i am beginning to suspect that there is something wrong with the list and perhaps I should recreate it.